# Running an axios.get inside a map function is returning a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a React application where I get a list of books' ids from my DB and I display them using these IDs to get the information from the GoogleBooks API. So I'm mapping through my props and for each book, I'll go for the API using the axios.get().
My problem is that it's returning an object Promise that I couldn't find where to handle.

this is the error it games me
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

thanks!

```
class HomeGroup extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchBooks();
    }
    renderBooks() {
        return this.props.books.map(async (book, index) => {
            const res = await axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:${book.ISBN}`);
            return <div key={index}>{res.data.items[0].id}</div>;
        });
        }
    render() {      
        return <div className="row">{this.renderBooks()}</div>;
    }
```

Comment: dont make requests in your render logic. Move that to be in a didMount, or didUpdate when your `fetchBooks` first api finishes

Comment: async function `async () => {}` always return promise

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to fetch data in a React component](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html), then it will be similar with your books.